# ARC Bluetooth support

Tags: android, google-chrome-arc

When running an Android app in ARC, BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter() currently returns null.

What is the status with Bluetooth support in ARC?

Thanks!

Observed with

ARC version:  41.4410.244.25

Chrome: 41.0.2272.118

Platform: OSX Yosemite 10.10.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have observed, we do not yet support Bluetooth in ARC.

Feel free to star [this bug](http://crbug.com/249008) which is about adding support for it.

Answer (score 0):

As stated, ARC doesn't currently support bluetooth or other hardware service level functions such as rear camera.  What has yet to be determined is if bluetooth support is ever going to come to ARC or whatever iteration Google decides to embed android app support into chromeweb/chromebook.